# Producing a deep-reverse procedure

Tags: lisp, scheme, sicp

> **Exercise 2.27**
>
> Modify your reverse
>   procedure of exercise 2.18 to produce
>   a deep-reverse procedure that takes a
>   list as argument and returns as its
>   value the list with its elements
>   reversed and with all sublists
>   deep-reversed as well. For example,
>
> ```
> (define x (list (list 1 2) (list 3
> 4)))
>
> x ((1 2) (3 4))
>
> (reverse x) ((3 4) (1 2))
>
> (deep-reverse x) ((4 3) (2 1))
> ```

I wrote the following:

```
(define (deep-reverse lis)
  (define (snoc elem lis)
    (if (null? lis) 
        (cons elem lis)
        (cons (car lis) (snoc elem (cdr lis)))))
  (cond ((null? lis) lis)
        ((pair? (car lis)) (snoc (deep-reverse (car lis)) (deep-reverse (cdr lis))))
        (else (snoc (car lis) (deep-reverse (cdr lis))))))

(define a (list 1 2 3 4 5 (list 1 2 3 4) (list 5 6 7 8)))
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with using `snoc` (or `append`, which your `snoc` effectively does) is that *each* call is O(n). This makes your function O(n²), which is (pun intended) deeply problematic.

Here's my O(n) implementation, which is tail-recursive along the `cdr`s:

```
(define (deep-reverse l)
  (let loop ((x l)
             (r '()))
    (cond ((null? x) r) 
          ((pair? x) (loop (cdr x) (cons (deep-reverse (car x)) r)))
          (else x))))
```

Here's an even shorter version, using `fold` (also tail-recursive along the `cdr`s):

```
(define (deep-reverse l)
  (define (iter x y)
    (cons (if (pair? x) (deep-reverse x) x) y))
  (fold iter '() l))
```

For even more fun, an `unfold-right` version (also tail-recursive along the `cdr`s); requires `compose` as well:

```
(define (deep-reverse l)
  (define (iter x)
    (if (pair? x) (deep-reverse x) x))
  (unfold-right null? (compose iter car) cdr l))
```